# populating a static unordered_map local variable

Tags: c++, static, unordered-map

I have a function which makes use of an unordered_map and its only this function in my class which uses it:

```
void my_func(){
    static std::unordered_map<int,int> my_map;

    //I only want this to be done the first time the function is called.
    my_map[1] = 1;
    my_map[2] = 3;
    //etc

}
```

How can I insert the elements in to my static unordered_map so that they only get inserted the first time my function is called (just like the memory allocation is only made the first time)?

Is it possible?

Comment: Use a `static bool` as a flag to check if it's initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 (which you're presumably using, otherwise there wouldn't be an `unordered_map`), containers can be populated by a list initialiser:

```
static std::unordered_map<int,int> my_map {
    {1, 1},
    {2, 3},
    //etc
};
```

Historically, the cleanest way would be to call a function that returns a populated container:

```
static std::unordered_map<int,int> my_map = make_map();
```

Comment: Got a feeling the MSVC and Intel compilers dont allow your first suggestion. I do like the second suggestion though :)

Comment: +1, and if the initializer list doesn't work (sometimes they're quirky), the `make_map` function can be a lambda expression.

Comment: @user997112 Intel tends to be the most compliant, and MSVC tends to be the least compliant, of the popular implementations.

Comment: @Potatoswatter GCC is the most compliant- then Intel :)

Comment: @user997112 The top 3 are all pretty impressive. They should all have solid initializer list support. But they do all have bugs :P .